# Horizontal and diagonal tables in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can a diagonal table columns/cells be implemented in HTML/CSS/Javascript?

I've been googling for several hours and the only resource I can find is splitting cells diagonally and not rotate part of a table/column.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Never use dropbox and other fileupload services, as they won't be accessible at many places. You already have received 2 close votes! Rephrase your question too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [@Giacomo1968 wrote in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514916/117259), you want to use `Div` or better `Ul` tag instead.
As for the turn, use CSS3 to rotate your finished table:

```
transform:rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(-45deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(-45deg); /* Opera */
```

So basically your table is made out of two tables, one is normal, other is using CSS3 to rotate.

Comment: Thanks folks. Using <div> for tabular data brings a lot of issues with it so I was hoping it's possible with tables, I guess it can't be helped. Cheers.

Comment: If you strongly want to, you can use tables there. I would not like to play with `<tr>`,`<td>`'s, but this is your call. As for the side numbers, rotate them backwards by `45deg` so it layout nicely.

Answer (score 0):

That seems complex to say the least. I would not attempt to do this with any `<table>` tags but rather in `<div>`, `<ul>` & `<li>` tags. But I believe it is doable with modern CSS options.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 tables here.Rotate the sq.ft. table, position behind the department table.After that you rotate back some of the content to initial position.The numbers without background-color could be part of the table resetting the bg color on them or separatelly of the table, like a list, rotated and positioned near the table.Have fun!